# Как добавить пустую папку в репозитории Git?

Tags: git, git-commit

Как добавить пустую папку (без файлов) в репозиторий Git? Вариант, закомитить папку с файлами, а потом их удалить - не подходит.

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/q/115983

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Полностью пустую папку создать нельзя, git не позволит.

Стандартная практика такая: в нужной папке создается пустой (0 байт) файл с именем `.gitkeep`. Можно добавить его, тогда git заметит и папку.

Распространённая [неудачная практика](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-can-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository): создавать файл с именем `.gitignore`. Это имя зарезервировано для другой задачи, не стоит использовать его не по назначению.

Answer (score 1):

Пустую директорию git не даст добавить в индекс.

Замечу, что не обязательно создавать файл с именем `.gitkeep`. Можно любое другое адекватное имя.

Я, например, практикую имя `.keepdir`. Можно просто `.keep`. Файл лучше создавать скрытым, так как он не несет никакой полезной информации.