# Создание папки в GitHub

Tags: git, github

Как создать папку в репозитории GitHub?

Comment: Потенциальным закрывающим: данный вопрос не является дублем «[Как добавить пустую папку в репозитории Git?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/623608/208074)», так как web-интерфейс Github-а позволяет создавать файлы только в имеющихся папках.

Comment: @Arhad автор не выставлял требование про веб-интерфейс.

Comment: @Arhad не вижу упомянутого вами ограничения в гитхабе...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ага, уже увидел в вашем ответе. Однако поле с подсказкой «Name your file» (задайте *имя* файла) как бы не предполагает ввод относительного *пути*.

Comment: @Arhad у нас гит или не гит? Путь к файлу - часть его имени.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, то есть имя файла — это не просто имя, сопоставленное неким tree object соответствующему blob-у? Неочевидно, однако. Но это больше вопрос терминологии, согласен.

Comment: А как работать студией в последствии с папками? Путь папки получается как: MyRepo/tree/main/MyFolder/ Но студия (плагин гитхаба) не видит такого репозитория чтобы его клонировать и лазивать файлы.

Comment: @Сергей в гите клонировать можно только корень репозитория. Работать с папками можно как обычно.

Answer (score 7):

Для того чтобы создать папку - нужно добавить в нее хотя бы один файл. Если стоит задача "просто создать папку" - можно добавить файл `.gitkeep`. Это "говорящее" имя файла обозначает что файл был создан исключительно для того чтобы гит знал о папке.

В веб-интерфейсе файл в новой папке создается следующим образом:

1. Нажимаем кнопку Create new file:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. В поле имени файла начинаем вводить полный путь к файлу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. Для отделения имени папки от имени файла используем прямую косую черту <kbd>/</kbd>. При этом отображение поля редактирования изменится:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4. После завершения ввода пути к файлу интерфейс гитхаба будет выглядеть примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

5. Осталось внизу ввести описание коммита и нажать кнопку "Commit new file"

Answer (score 3):

Пустую папку создать нельзя, т.к. `git` имеет дело с файлами, коими папка не является.

Если же вам таки нужно что-то типа пустой папки создать, то поместите в пустую папку файл `.gitkeep` и закоммитте его - в репозитории появится папка с этим файлом.

---

Если это нужно сделать силами веб-интерфейса, то надо создать файл, указав в его имени путь к нему. Т.е., создавая файл с именем `testFolder/.gitkeep` будет помимо файла `.gitignore` создана и папка `testFolder`. После создания вам будет предложено либо закоммитить прямо в мастер или создать отдельную ветку и `pull-request` в мастер

Comment: Речь, скорее всего, идёт о том, что сам Github даёт возможность создания файлов только в уже существующих папках (а вопрошающему хочется сделать всё силами web интерфейса, без перехода в git-клиент).

Comment: @Arhad, возможно вы правы) К сожалению, ТС не раскрыл детали, вот я и сделал предположение о возможной сути вопроса)

Comment: @Arhad, про создание папки через веб-интерфейс тоже написал)

Comment: Таки лучше `.gitkeep`, это имя явно обозначает цель, с которой файл добавлен.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, исправил)